# Python: create multiple new columns based on patterns

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
#chr    start   end count   colX    colY
1   100 200 1       
1   300 400 2   blabla_pattern_a,blabla_pattern_b,blabla_pattern_c
2   100 400 1   blabla_pattern_a    
2   500 600 4   blabla_pattern_e,blabla_pattern_c   blabla_pattern_d
```

I am looking for 5 different patterns (a-e) that could be present in `colX` and `colY`. `ColX` and/or `ColY` can also be empty in some cases. Based on presence/absence of these patterns, I would like to create 5 different columns with values `X`, `Y` or `NA` like this:

```
#chr    start   end count   pattern_a   pattern_b   pattern_c   pattern_d   pattern_e   
1   100 200 1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
1   300 400 2   X   X   X   NA  NA
2   100 400 1   Y   NA  NA  NA  NA
2   500 600 4   NA  NA  X   Y   X
```

I know how to do this for one pattern, but I need help to do this efficiently for multiple patterns. Here is my code so far -- which works for one pattern:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import csv
   import sys
   input_file = sys.argv[1]
   with open(input_file, 'rU') as f:
       data = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
       a=[]
       for row in data:
           if "pattern_a" in row[4]:
               a = "X"
           elif "pattern_a" in row[5]:
               a = "Y"
           else:
               a = "NA"
           print (row,a)
```

Comment: what about a `for` loop over the `patterns = ['pattern_a', 'pattern_b', 'pattern_c', pattern_d', 'pattern_e']`?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am not sure how to combine the loop for patterns and the if/else condition and store the results for each pattern search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that might work:

```
import csv
import sys

input_file = sys.argv[1]
patterns = ['pattern_a', 'pattern_b', 'pattern_c', 'pattern_d', 'pattern_e']

with open(input_file, 'rU') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')

    for row in data:
        a=[]
        for pattern in patterns:
            if pattern in row[4]:
                a.append("X")
            elif pattern in row[5]:
                a.append("Y")
            else:
                a.append("NA")
        print (a)
```

Output of this is:

```
['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'NA', 'NA']
['X', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
['NA', 'NA', 'X', 'Y', 'X']
```